# XMPPFramework - How to create a group chat room?

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I have an application which I am using for one-to-one chat. Now I need to implement group chat. I know it is possible with XMPPFramework and there is a class called XMPPRoom which we can use to create a room or join a room. But I am unable to implement that in my project.

Can anyone please provide me some ideas, suggestions and if possible a sample application.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why are you unable to implement that in your project? What have you tried? What specific problem are you encountering. Please don't use StackOverflow as a place to ask people to do your work for you.

Comment: Take a read at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786813/xmppframework-how-to-create-a-muc-room-and-invite-users/24179388#24179388

Answer (score 2):

here you have a script that allows to connect to a room

```
[xmppRoom activate:[self xmppStream]]; 
[xmppRoom createOrJoinRoom];
```

In order to do this you should have access to the xmppStream.

Comment: This is the new method: 
`[xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:@"keithoys" history:nil];`

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)createOrJoinRoomWithRoomName:(NSString *)roomName nickName:(NSString *)nickName 
    {
        if(roomName && nickName)
        {
            _xmppRoomStorage = [XMPPRoomHybridStorage sharedInstance];
            XMPPJID *roomJid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@.%@",roomName,@"conference",self.hostName]];
            _xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:_xmppRoomStorage jid:roomJid];
            [_xmppRoom addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
            [_xmppRoom activate:_xmppStream];
            NSXMLElement *history = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"history"];
            [history addAttributeWithName:@"maxstanzas" stringValue:MAX_ROOM_HISTORY];
            [_xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:nickName history:history];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"room creation arguments missing");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi suhail ,
can you please explain what is  MAX_ROOM_HISTORY ?  -------
it will show me error like "use of undeclared identifier MAX_ROOM_HISTORY"

Comment: hi, thats my own # define value, u can give any integer value thre