# Create Group Chat using XMPP

Tags: xmpp, xmppframework

I'm creating a Chat application, i have done one-to-one chat, but unable to approach how to create chatRoom and add people.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XMPPFramework - How to create a MUC room and invite users?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786813/xmppframework-how-to-create-a-muc-room-and-invite-users)

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9032279/113848).

Answer (score 0):

I think this link will give you call the necessary information: 
http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html.

In simple terms varying the resource while logging in to the server allows multiple users to be affiliated to a single login i.e. the single login does the work of a chat room.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create group for group chat.
Use below function for create group

```
-(void)joinMultiUserChatRoom:(NSString *)RoomName
    XMPPRoomHybridStorage *xmppRoomStorage1 = [XMPPRoomHybridStorage sharedInstance];
XMPPJID *chatRoomJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:RoomName];
xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:xmppRoomStorage1 jid:chatRoomJID];
[xmppRoom addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xmppRoom activate:xmppStream];
NSXMLElement *history = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"history"];
[history addAttributeWithName:@"maxstanzas" stringValue:@"1"];
[xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:self.xmppStream.myJID.user history:nil];
```